# Usage of executor service in Lmax Disruptor

Tags: java, disruptor-pattern, lmax

I am evaluating the Disruptor library for a data processing application platform. Specifically I would evaluate against Akka actor framework and plain Java executor service, fitting to our problem domain.

For instantiating a new Disruptor (queue, should I say?), we need to provide an instance of ExecutorService (v3.3.2). When I check sample codes for Disruptor, in almost every cases I see cached thread pool is being passed. I have a single consumer (EventHandler) scenario. In such a condition, is there any difference if I use a single thread executor instead?